# SQL - Multiple case when functions

Tags: mysql, sql, optimization

I have an issue relating to an earlier post I made (for ref: [SQL - How to find optimal performance numbers for query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44456398/sql-how-to-find-optimal-performance-numbers-for-query))

Essentially, I am now trying to use the CASE WHEN function to make a variety of different groups. For example, and following the example from the previous post, I have the following:

```
SELECT

     Vehicle_type,
     case when Number_of_passengers::numeric = 0 then 'cat=0'
     when Number_of_passengers::numeric < 2 then 'cat1<2'
     when Number_of_passengers::numeric < 3 then 'cat1<3'
     when Number_of_passengers::numeric < 4 then 'cat1<4'
     when Number_of_passengers::numeric < 5 then 'cat1<5'
     when Number_of_passengers::numeric < 6 then 'cat1<6'
     when Number_of_passengers::numeric < 7 then 'cat1<7' 
     when Number_of_passengers::numeric > 2 then 'cat1>2'
     when Number_of_passengers::numeric > 3 then 'cat1>3'
     when Number_of_passengers::numeric > 4 then 'cat1>4'
     when Number_of_passengers::numeric > 5 then 'cat1>5'
     when Number_of_passengers::numeric > 6 then 'cat1>6'
     when Number_of_passengers::numeric > 7 then 'cat1>7'end as category1,
     case when Number_of_doors::numeric = 0 then 'cat2=0'
     when Number_of_doors::numeric > 2 then 'cat2>2'
     when Number_of_doors::numeric > 3 then 'cat2>3'
     when Number_of_doors::numeric > 4 then 'cat2>4'
     when Number_of_doors::numeric > 5 then 'cat2>5'
     when Number_of_doors::numeric > 6 then 'cat2>6'
     when Number_of_doors::numeric > 7 then 'cat2>7' 
     when Number_of_doors::numeric < 2 then 'cat2<2'
     when Number_of_doors::numeric < 3 then 'cat2<3'
     when Number_of_doors::numeric < 4 then 'cat2<4'
     when Number_of_doors::numeric < 5 then 'cat2<5'
     when Number_of_doors::numeric < 6 then 'cat2<6'
     when Number_of_doors::numeric < 7 then 'cat2<7' end as category2,
     round(sum(case when in_accident='t' then 1.0 end)/ count(*),3) as accident_rate,

FROM Accidents

GROUP by 1,2,3
```

This is actually giving me the correct output in terms of format, however, the numbers I receive in the 'accident_rate'column vary.

If i ran this whole query, I get a different accident_rate for the groups than if i looked at groups individually.

To explain, if i ran the above query and looked at : Car, Number_of_passengers > 2 and  Number_of_doors > 2, my accident rate could be 60%.

Yet, if i ran the query as:

```
SELECT

    Vehical_type,
    case when Number_of_passengers::numeric > 2 then 'cat1>2' end as category1,
    case when Number_of_doors::numeric > 2 then 'cat2>2' end as category2,
    round(sum(case when in_accident='t' then 1.0 end)/ count(*),3) as accident_rate,

FROM Accidents

GROUP by 1,2,3
```

my accident rate might only be 20%.

Any suggestion guys?

Thanks

Comment: Instead of using  a huge query with case statement why don't you create a table with car descriptions with doors and No of passengers, in this table add the cols (Cat1>1 etc...) with a 0/1 label if the car fits the description.
Then you can compute the accident rate. I think it's better to "denormalize" a bit.

Comment: Optimal performance can be achieved by handling issues of data display in the presentation layer.

Comment: Thanks for the comments guys, you're correct about making a table and I will start working on that, was hoping to leave this as a template so people could edit variables as they see fit

Comment: Realized the reason for different stats, as my groupings are not mutually exclusive they will of course give altered results